# Trying to clean up wrong CSS rules using js code

Tags: javascript, regex

I have bad css files with rules like this (I can't control the generation of these files):

```
.class html {
}

.class2 html,.class3 html {

}

html {

}

html .class4 {

}

.class body {
}

.class2 body,.class3 body {    
}

body {    
}

body .class4 {    
}
```

as you can see, some HTML and BODY rules are put *after* class name.

What I want to do is to reverse this rules to obtain proper qualifier (tag then class).

My expected result is:

```
html .class  {
}

html .class2 ,html .class3  {

}

html {

}

html .class4 {

}

body .class  {
}

body .class2 ,body .class3  {

}

body {

}

body .class4 {

}
```

I tried using a regex : `([^,]+\s+)(html|body)` with this substitution : `$2 $1`, but I don't get what I want. ([Repro on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kM9kZ7/1))

How to reach my goal ?

PS: this will ends in a custom gulp task, so a js regex solution is required.

Comment: Or try [`(\.\S+)(\s+)(html|body)` --> `$3$2$1`](https://regex101.com/r/kM9kZ7/2).

Comment: @Tushar: only body and html tag are concerned; because they are higher in the dom than my root classes;

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: this worked. You should add an answer so I can reward you

Comment: wondering why downvote...

Comment: @SteveB, it wasn't me but I'm guessing because you haven't really explained what you have tried in order to solve the issue yourself. Especially where this solution looks like you're asking for a hack. Why can't you just your CSS instead?

Comment: This a hack I requested for. I assume that. The css come actually from a custom bootstrap-sass wrapper to scope bootstrap within my page. I don't want to tweak bootstrap file to keep it unchanged and to avoid merging troubles with future release. My hack is very isolated and I can live with that. It's only a scss wrapper file over bs entry scss file. The wrong output is the result of the sass language behavior.

Comment: remove `html` and `body` that are useless. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(\.\S+)(\s+)(html|body)
```

and replace with `$3$2$1`.

The regex demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/kM9kZ7/2).

**Expression details**:

- `(\.\S+)` - a literal dot followed with one or more non-whitespaces (Group 1)
- `(\s+)` - one or more whitespaces (Group 2)
- `(html|body)` - either `html` or `body` literal character sequences (Group 3).

The replacement pattern contains the group backreferences that follow in the opposite direction for swapping to occur.

To account for cases like `.class .classN html`, use

```
/(\.\S+(?:\s+\.\S+)*)(\s+)(html|body)/g
```

where a noncapturing group `(?:\s+\.\S+)*` is quantified with `*` ((zero or more times).

Comment: Works perfectly. As a side note, in my gulpfile I put `.pipe(replace(/(\.\S+)(\s+)(html|body)/g,'$3$2$1')) // Tweak rules order (html and body before classname)` to include this tweak.

Comment: hum, not actually an issue in my case, but this fails if two classes are defined before the html tag (ex: `.class1 .class2 html` is converted to `.class1 html .class2`

Comment: I added this scenario regex to the answer. Sorry for slow typing on my mobile.